# How to get python graph output from yfinance into HTML webpage directly?

Tags: python, html, graph, web-frontend, yfinance

I'm working on Python Flask for this project. I have been using different packages to make the stock graph (Plotly and Finplot). I'm still new to the front end stuff. Not sure why the graph is not outputting. I'm not sure if using matplotlib would have better results to display a graph in HTML page.

Here is part of my python code so far:

```
@app.route("/plot", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def generate_plot():
    yf.pdr_override() # Not sure if I need this for datareader
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = request.form
        if('ticker' in form):
            ticker = form['ticker'] # When users select a ticker from my dropdown list
            ticker = ticker.upper()

            # Eg. yfinance downloads a table of AAPL period of 1 day and interval of 1 year.
            df = yf.download(tickers=ticker,period='1d',interval='1y') 
            fig = go.Figure()
            fig.add_trace(go.Line(x=df.index,
                open=df['Open'],
                high=df['High'],
                low=df['Low'],
                close=df['Close'], name = 'market data'))
            
            fig.update_layout(
                title= str(stock)+' Live Share Price:',
                yaxis_title='Stock Price (USD per Shares)') 
            
            fig.update_xaxes(
                rangeslider_visible=True,
                rangeselector=dict(
                    buttons=list([
                        dict(count=15, label="15m", step="minute", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=45, label="45m", step="minute", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(count=1, label="HTD", step="hour", stepmode="todate"),
                        dict(count=3, label="3h", step="hour", stepmode="backward"),
                        dict(step="all")
                    ])
                )
            )
    fig.write_image('static/images/plot.png') # Save the png and then supply the path to the file in the html
    # return base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()) # I was trying encode the img to base64 format.

@app.route("/")
def index():
    # we will use Flask's render_template method to render a website template.
    plot_path = generate_plot()
    return render_template("stock.html", plot_graph=plot_path)
```

My HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="static/images/plot.png" alt="Plot">
    </div>
</body>
```

- I tried saving the image directly. I thought the webpage would display the picture, however the graph wouldn't appear.
- I tried encoding the graph into base64 and output it in HTML file. The same result as saving image directly.
- I tried using finplot screenshot function, but the graph didn't appear as well.